# Potential Energy of two masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

If two particles with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ interact and are located at $\vec{s_1}$ and $\vec{s_2}$ have their potential energy $U$ defined by the modulus of their position vectors, how would I determine the forces from the potential in order to determine the equations of motion for the masses and the center-of-mass? That is, the potential energy is of the general form $a|\vec{s_1}-\vec{s_2}|^n$. I tried to determine the force by using the fact that the force would be the negative gradient of the given potential energy, i.e., $$\nabla_{\vec{s}_1} a\lvert \vec{s}_1-\vec{s}_2 \rvert^n =
a\,n\,\lvert \vec{s}_1-\vec{s}_2 \rvert^{n-2}(\vec{s}_1-\vec{s}_2),$$ and $$\nabla_{\vec{s}_2} a\lvert \vec{s}_1-\vec{s}_2 \rvert^n =
-a\,n\,\lvert \vec{s}_1-\vec{s}_2 \rvert^{n-2}(\vec{s}_1-\vec{s}_2).$$

However, is there a better way to find force equations in terms of its components in order to determine the motion equations for the two particles?

Comment: If you know the potential you cal always use euler-lagrange formula to get the equation of motion.

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? That equation for force is correct, and I don't see a way it could be simplified, but there might be a different way to arrive at the same formula. What's wrong with this way that you're seeking a "better way"?